# Sharp expectancy - what does "sharp" express here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Trying to understand the following sentence from H.P. Lovecraft's Tree:

> Many months passed, yet in the sour face of Musides came nothing of
> the sharp expectancy which the situation should arouse.

There are so many meanings in the dictionary so that I cannot infer the right one here. THanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Sharp' here means 'intense'. Musides might have been expected to feel intense expectancy in that situation, but evidently did not.

> 2.4 (of an emotion or experience)
> felt acutely or intensely; painful.
> ‘her sharp disappointment was tinged with embarrassment’

[Sharp (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sharp)